# How to edit the CSV file using JMeter means to overwrite the data in the CSV?

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

akshaygarg30,akshay.garg+30@jitterbit.com,NewUser,7Iron-hide

I want to make "NewUser" to Activated in the CSV through the beanshell script or through any other way in the jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function to [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) "NewUser" with "Activated" on the fly like:

Given "NewUser" lives in `${status}` JMeter Variable:

```
`${__javaScript("${status}".replace("${status}"\,"Activated"),)}`
```

Demo:

[image: JavaScript Replace demo]

---

If for some reason you need to replace it in the whole file - it can be done in Beanshell Test Element of your choice using the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

File csvFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.csv");
String fileData = FileUtils.readFileToString(csvFile);
fileData = fileData.replaceAll("NewUser", "Activated");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(csvFile, fileData);
```

It mostly uses [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class, methods should be self-explanatory. Check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.